# Good Books for Iphone sdk and Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.2

I have choosen Iphone as my profession and I am working on it for making my career on this particular field.Since from last few weeks I am searching on for good books on Iphone sdk and on obj-c with topics included like:

Total UI Controls , UI Delegates And all Foundation Framework classes like NSString, NSArray etc, About Memory Management, CFNetwork, some sample iphone application Programs.

I saw some books in book stores but couldn't able to decide which book to buy. can you please help me in giving me some best book names where I can find all the topics.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [iPhone SDK Development](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/amiphd/iphone-sdk-development) is a good start.

Answer (score 3):

Though not a book, I would recommend checking out the free [Stanford class from Itunes U](http://itunes.stanford.edu/).  Just looks up iPhone Application Development or Iphone Application Programming.

They go through all the basics as well as APIs for NSString and NSArray, etc if only cursory.  If you get a chance, also try to get a hold of the assignments.  You can google for them since they take down the assignments from semester to semester.  Just go along with them and try them out as best as you can.  That helped me out a great deal when learning iPhone development.

Answer (score 1):

I'm starting with "Programming in Objective-C 2.0 (Developer's Library)" and it seems really good.
For iphone sdk have a look at "Phone SDK Development: Building iPhone Applications (With Source Code)"

Answer (score 0):

I started learning to develop for iPhone last week, and I've been using both [Head First iPhone Development](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596803551) and [iPhone SDK Development](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/amiphd/iphone-sdk-development). They are both great in conjunction with each other. I've been using the head first book when running through exercises hands-on at the computer, and the pragmatic book as more of a reference book to read on-the-go.